# Import "keyboard" could not be resolved from source error

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

This is a problem I kept having on VS Code even though I have the module(s) installed, I still get the error[This is the import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCC4K.png)[and I was wondering if anyone knows what to do with this "no console" problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGuHv.png)

I've been quite stuck with these two for a while now, the code won't run after satisfying the dependencies on python

I have already tried restarting VS Code, used all methods I found on the internet to fix the import problem and still have the import errors showing up, and now Im suspecting the "no console" problem.

Comment: Please, add errors as text.

Comment: Import "keyboard" could not be resolved from Pylance(reportMIssingImports)

and (no console) for python

Comment: I found a fix, question closed

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)